# Error: Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

I have a backup from database in SQL Server 2008 R2.
When I want to restore this backup to SQL Server, I get this error:
"Error: Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)"
How to I resolve this error?
Thanks.

Comment: WITH MOVE `'YourMDFLogicalName' TO 'D:\DataYourMDFFile.mdf', `-adjust path
MOVE `'YourLDFLogicalName' TO 'D:\DataYourLDFFile.ldf'` mdf ldf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some [funnies](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/071DA5BB-32C5-4C3F-9378-7E67C5DF2D44) restoring old databases into SQL 2008 via the guy; have you tried doing it via TSQL ?

```
Use Master
Go
RESTORE DATABASE YourDB
FROM DISK = 'C:\YourBackUpFile.bak'
WITH MOVE 'YourMDFLogicalName' TO 'D:\Data\YourMDFFile.mdf',--check and adjust path
MOVE 'YourLDFLogicalName' TO 'D:\Data\YourLDFFile.ldf'
```

Comment: The name of the file in SQL Server. In Management STudio; open a query; use the database you are working on backing up run select Name from sys files its the Name column.

Comment: For the noobs like me. The comment of u07ch is correct but contains a typo in the query: 
  select name from sysfiles

Answer (score 18):

This would also happen when you are trying to restore a newer version backup in a  older SQL database. For example when you try to restore a DB backup that is created in 2012 with 110 compatibility and you are trying to restore it in 2008 R2.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it happens because of the version change like store 2012 db on 2008, so how to check it?

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'd:\yourbackup.bak'
```

if it gives error like:

Msg 3241, Level 16, State 13, Line 2
The media family on device 'd:\alibaba.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Check it further:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'd:\yourbackup.bak'
```

BackupName is "*** INCOMPLETE ***",
Position is "1",
other fields are "NULL".

Means either your backup is corrupt or taken from newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error "Specified cast is not valid" restoring from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2

First I got the MDF and LDF Names:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Users\dell laptop\DotNetSandBox\DBBackups\Davincis3.bak' 
GO
```

Second I restored with a MOVE using those names returned:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Davincis3 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\dell laptop\DotNetSandBox\DBBackups\Davincis3.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'JQueryExampleDb' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Davincis3.mdf', 
   MOVE 'JQueryExampleDB_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Davincis3.ldf', 
REPLACE
GO
```

I have no clue as to the name "JQueryExampleDb", but this worked for me.

Nevertheless, backups (and databases) are not backwards compatible with older versions.